# Sitemesh work with velocity #parse not right worked

Tags: java, struts, velocity, sitemesh

Now I work with struts、sitemesh、velocity， and the config already can use

In the main page：

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
    #parse("common/taglibs.vm")
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="body-0214">
    #parse("/velocity/info/head.vm")
    $body
    #parse("/velocity/info/foot.vm")
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In taglibs.vm I had define some global variable：

```
#set ($ctx=$request.contextPath)
#set ($imageService=$controlUtil.getDomainName($session.servletContext))
```

when in the `head.vm` and `main.vm`  I try get the global variable：

```
$ctx
$imageService
```

and get result ：

```
$ctx
$imageService
```

no any change！

but when I put `#parse("common/taglibs.vm")` in `main.vm`(the result page) it get the right result:

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

this is a problem : why must recommend  `#parse("common/taglibs.vm")`  in children page， the other proble is when I put `#parse("common/taglibs.vm")` in `head.vm`, It also not work , I am very suprised

why I got that result ， is any where I was wrong or always been that way， please help me！

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing a configuration problem or something that is completely outside of Velocity.

Let's start by simplifying things. For a test put all the following vm-templates in the same folder. Best put them in the folder that is declared to be the Velocity resource loader path or Velocity root.

**First step:**

taglib.vm:

```
#set($ctx = $request.contextPath)
```

main.vm:

```
#parse("taglibs.vm")
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-0214">
            $ctx
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result will be the context path - in your case `http://127.0.0.1`. According to what you posted this should work.

**Second step:**

Create a file `head.vm` like this:

```
$ctx
```

and change `main.vm` to this:

```
#parse("taglibs.vm")
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-0214">
            #parse("head.vm")
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result should be the same.

**Third step:**

Create a file `secondLevel.vm`:

```
$ctx
```

Yes, same context as head.vm by now.

Now change `head.vm` to

```
#parse("secondLevel.vm")
```

In default configuration this will still produce the same result. If not there is a chance that the default configuration was altered. If you see `$ctx` instead of `http://127.0.0.1` check the Velocity configuration. Look for `parse_directive.maxdepth`. The value should be above `1`.
Please note, that default value is `10` so you could parse up to 10 nested vm-files by default.

If you fail to see the desired results in the first or second step, I'd suggest to test that in a completely new project, to eliminate side effects.

Although not likely to cause the problem, make sure your on the latest version of Velocity 1.7